# c# deleting duplicate rows from data table

Tags: c#, database, datatable, duplicates

I'm currently having a problem with my C# code; it is producing duplicate lines in my data table but not in my database itself. I can't for the life of me find whats causing it, so I've tried creating a work around, how ever that doesn't seem to be working either. Any help would be appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i ++ )
{

    for(int n = 0; n< ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; n++)
    { 
        if (n == i)
        {
            //do nothing

        }
        else
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i] == ds.Tables[0].Rows[n])
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[n].Delete();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should definitely spend your time figuring out what the root problem is instead of fixing the symptoms

Comment: Before inserting a record into your data table, verify that it doesn't already exist. How did you find dups were getting in the data table when they don't end up in the database?

Comment: Have you stepped through you code line by line to try and find the issue?

Comment: I've honestly looked for the root cause but simply cannot find it, im very much a novice at the moment.
i found the problem as  i have a list box which displays all the contents of the datatable.
however i make sure this is cleared before each change, so it must be the datatable causing the problem.

Comment: `ds.Tables[0].Rows[i] == ds.Tables[0].Rows[n]` will probably never be true because they aren't the same row and I doubt the EqualityComparer for DataRow actually compares all the values of the columns.  And that assumes no row has an identity column in which case they would never be the same anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your issue is related with equality comparer try to map DataRow (difficult to hanlde as is) on more simple POCO class (a small class used only ad data model.

Then use group by or distinct to filter your data.

Here a little example :

The POCO class

```
public class DataRowModel
    {
        public object FirstCellData { get; set; }
        public object SecondCellData { get; set; }
        //... for every column in DataRow
        public object LastCellData { get; set; }

        public DataRowModel (DataRow row)
        {
            this.FirstCellData = row["FIELD_1"] ;
            this.SecondCellData = row["FIELD_2"];
            this.LastCellData = row["FIELD_3"];
        }
    }
```

The code to achieve unique rows :

```
        List<DataRowModel> rows = new List<DataRowModel> ();

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            rows.Add( new DataRowModel ( row) );

        List<DataRowModel> uniqueRows = new List<DataRowModel> ();
        foreach (var groupedRow in rows.GroupBy(x => new { x.FirstCellData, x.SecondCellData, /*.. for each cell..*/ x.LastCellData }))
            uniqueRows.Add(groupedRow.First());
```